# NX MCD and Beckhoff PLC connection

Tags: opc-ua, twincat, nomachine-nx

Hei everyone!

I am working on a project in TwinCAT3 and want to simulate how it would behave in real world. I am trying to control my SolidWorks model using HMI in a project. I found that it is possible to make a connection between NX MCD and Beckhoff PLC. But there is a little information about it.

I saw that there is possibility with EDAG solution, but it is outdated and I haven't really found out how to make it. I know there is also a solution using OPC UA in Beckhoff and somehow connect it to NX MCD.

Note : I have a Student version of NX

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. [Here is an example](http://dronefactory.co.uk/) how to connect it to Unity, maybe you can use that to make it work.